# XDebug doesn't work with Eclipse PHP on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, xdebug

I have problems with (x)debugging on Eclipse PHP (Helios). It worked fine before my upgrade from Ubuntu 10 to 12, but now it doesn't.

I added this to php.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5_3.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=laptopname
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey="ECLIPSE_DBGP"
extension=imap.so
```

and the settings of Eclipse (XDebug) are:

```
Debug Port : 9000
Show super globals in variable view : ticked
Max array depth : 7
Max children : 100
Use Multisession : ticked
Accept remote session (JIT) : any
Output Capture Settings : both copy
DBGp Proxy Support : not ticked
```

I'm thankful for any hint or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are loading **xdebug.so**

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5_3.so
```

and the following line is redundant

```
xdebug.remote_host=laptopname
```

because, you are using

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```